# Preparing for segue crashes when instantiating controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swift2, segue

I'm struggling to figure out the error message I get in the `prepareForSegue()` method. The code that I'm using in this method is the same as in the default Master-Default template in Xcode.

But in my case, this line crashed the application:

```
let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! SummaryViewController
```

With the following error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I have declared the destination view controller in the top with `var summaryViewController: SummaryViewController? = nil` and I have a segue from the current view controller to the `SummaryViewController`, and this `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("showSummary", sender: self)
}
```

But I have also tried with a segue directly from the tableview cell, (and removing this method), but it still crashes.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the VC is nil or not so your `prepareForSegue` must be like following:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showSummary"
        {
            if let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as? UINavigationController)!.topViewController as? SummaryViewController
            {
              // write a the code for SummaryViewController
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm currently trying to learn Swift, and all the ! and ? is throwing me off.. :-)

Comment: ? means may be value come in Nil and ! must be value not nil